# Silex - why is app suddenly undefined in my controller

Tags: php, silex

In my silex project my $app variable is suddenly undefined in my controller although I can use it on the previous instruction in dump() or to call monolog.

Any idea why that is ?

My only modification to index_dev.php is commenting the code preventing to access an application with debug set to true from a different ip (non localhost).

In config/dev.php the only not commented modification is :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\VarDumperServiceProvider());
```

In src/app.php I only commented the part where twig is added as a service.

And finally src/controller.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

//Request::setTrustedProxies(array('127.0.0.1'));
$app['monolog']->error('controller file');
dump($app);

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {

    return $app->json(array(getcwd(), basename(__DIR__)));
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Revert your changes to a working state, then reapply one by one.

Comment: I tried that and it did nothing (so I'm clearly missing something). Then I created a new bare-bone silex app in the same way I created the first one but without any modification. It works. The problem is when I diff between the files of the two app, nothing comes out that would explain my problem. I'll incrementally add my modification to the new project. At the same time I'll leave this question open in case someone find a solution or I found one and can share it.

Comment: Can you paste the diff somewhere?